# Host TabItem from Another Assembly

Tags: c#, wpf, tabs

I am trying to create a user control which is basically include a Tab Item. As follows and try to add it to my tab control in another library.

```
//Grid.xaml in a.dll

<UserControl x:Name="Grid" x:Class="SomeClass"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

    <TabItem Header="Grid">
        <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    </TabItem>

</UserControl>

//TabView.xaml in b.dll
<UserControl
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:Views="clr-namespace:SomeClass;assembly=SomeAssembly" x:Class="SomeClass" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

    <TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >

        <Views:GridView/>

        <TabItem Header="This" />
        <TabItem Header="That" />


    </TabControl>
</UserControl>
```

My problem is that, it actually creates the tab there, but does not show the header of tab. I wonder if I am doing it right and how can I show the header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your control in a.dll is not TabItem. It is UserControl. You can either inherit it from TabItem (it`s a bad way for WPF) or use composition:

```
//Grid.xaml in a.dll
<UserControl x:Name="Grid" x:Class="SomeClass"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

    <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>

</UserControl>


//TabView.xaml in b.dll
<UserControl
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:Views="clr-namespace:SomeClass;assembly=SomeAssembly" x:Class="SomeClass" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

    <TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >

        <TabItem Header="Grid">
            <Views:GridView/>
        </TabItem>

        <TabItem Header="This" />
        <TabItem Header="That" />


    </TabControl>
</UserControl>
```